# Creating a new file error

Tags: c#

When I try to create a temporary file that is stored in the server i get

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process.

To create the file I use the below code

```
public override void SaveAs(string filename)
{
    using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.CreateNew))
    stream.CopyTo(file);
}
```

I have searched and the solutions i get is for when the file is being read.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to create a file with a name that already exists. Are you passing in the same name every time?

Comment: MSDN says that if the file already exists the function throws such an exception.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you need unique file names, I recommend you to use [Path.GetTempFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)

```
public override string SaveStreamInTempFile()
{
    string tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
    using (var file = File.Open(tempFileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
    stream.CopyTo(file);

    return tempFileName;
}
```

Comment: `GetTempFileName()` Actually creates the file.  `GetRandomFileName()` does not create a file, but creates a much stronger random filename to use. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx